# Dependency is not renamed

Tags: reactjs, npm

I recently created a project with Gatsby. While I'm trying to use @emotion/core and @emotion/styled it shows me an error.

> See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.dev/debug-html  The `@emotion/core` package has been renamed to `@emotion/react`. Please import it like this `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'`.

2 |

> 3 | throw new Error("The `@emotion/core` package has been renamed to `@emotion/react`. Please import it like this `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'`.");
> | ^
> 4 |

WebpackError: The `@emotion/core` package has been renamed to `@emotion/react`. Please import it like this `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'`.

- emotion-core.cjs.dev.js:3
  node_modules/@emotion/core/dist/emotion-core.cjs.dev.js:3:1
- emotion-core.cjs.js:6
  node_modules/@emotion/core/dist/emotion-core.cjs.js:6:20
- gatsby-ssr.js:9
  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest/gatsby-ssr.js:9:15`enter code here`

I already renamed it and imported as it shows there. I also tried with Gatsby clean and deleted the node_modules and installed again, but still got the error. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and resolved by downgrading the @emotion/core package.

```
npm install @emotion/core@10.1.1
```